# Concurrent Dictionary reading and removing items In parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

**Question background:**

I am currently learning about concurrent operations using the.NET 6 `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop.

I have created the following program which features two Tasks running parallel to each other in a `Task.WhenAll` function. The `KeepAliveAsync` method runs up to 3 degrees of parallelism on the `HttpClient` calls for a total list of ten items. The `DisposeAsync` method will remove these items from the concurrent dictionary but before this, the `CleanItemBeforeDisposal` method removes the property values of the Item object.

**Code:**

```
{
    [TestClass]
    public class DisposeTests
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Item> items = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Item>();

        private bool keepAlive = true;

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test()
        {
            //Arrange
            string uri = "https://website.com";

            IEnumerable<int> itemsToAdd = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
            IEnumerable<int> itemsToDispose = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

            foreach (var itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
            {
                items.TryAdd(itemToAdd, new Item { Uri = uri });
            }

            //Act
            await Task.WhenAll(KeepAliveAsync(), DisposeAsync(itemsToDispose));

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(items.Count == 0);
        }

        private async Task KeepAliveAsync()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            do
            {
                ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3,
                };

                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(items.ToArray(), parallelOptions, async (item, token) =>
                {
                    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(item.Value.Uri);

                    item.Value.DataResponse = response;

                    item.Value.DataResponse.ToUpper();
                });

            } while (keepAlive == true);
        }

        private async Task DisposeAsync(IEnumerable<int> itemsToRemove)
        {
            var itemsToDisposeFiltered = items.ToList().FindAll(a => itemsToRemove.Contains(a.Key));

            ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3,
            };

            await Parallel.ForEachAsync(itemsToDisposeFiltered.ToArray(), parallelOptions, async (itemsToDispose, token) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);

                CleanItemBeforeDisposal(itemsToDispose);

                bool removed = items.TryRemove(itemsToDispose);

                if (removed == true)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"DisposeAsync - Removed item {itemsToDispose.Key} from the list");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"DisposeAsync - Did not remove item {itemsToDispose.Key} from the list");
                }
            });

            keepAlive = false;
        }

        private void CleanItemBeforeDisposal(KeyValuePair<int, Item> itemToDispose)
        {
            itemToDispose.Value.Uri = null;
            itemToDispose.Value.DataResponse = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Issue:**

The code runs but I am running into an issue where the `Uri` property of the Item object is being set null from the `CleanItemBeforeDisposal` method as called from the `Dispose` method by design but then the `HttpClient` call is being made in the parallel `KeepAliveAsync` method at which point the shared Item object is null and errors with:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

I have used the `ToArray` method on the shared `ConcurrentDictionary` as I believe this will create a snapshot of the dictionary at the time it is called but obviously this wont solve this race condition.

**What is the correct way to go about handling a situation where two processes are accessing one shared list where there is the possibility one process has changed properties of an entity of that list which the other process requires?**

Comment: In my humble opinion your question is not very appetizing, because it is focused too much on the internal mechanics of an operation, instead of giving a broader picture of the problem that needs to be solved. For example the broader problem might be that you want to download some stuff from the internet in parallel, but with a limited degree of parallelism. In which case we could just tell you that that there are already available tools that are doing exactly this, so there is no need to reinvent them.

Comment: I echo Theo's concerns. The way this is coded is not ideal in a number of ways. It seems like a lot of work to learn one method.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for your reply. I guess my question boils down to: what is the correct way of handling a situation where two processes are accessing one shared list where there is the possibility one process has changed properties of an entity of that list which the other process requires. I will edit the question with the above.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your reply. I have replied to Theodor with the crux of my issue. Can you elaborate further on what exactly you feel is wrong with the current code and where/what you would change.

Comment: @Dev - You `lock (...) { ... }` on every access of every shared object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer the question directly without getting into details about the design, etc.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is thread safe, meaning that multiple threads can safely add and remove items from the dictionary. That thread safety does not apply at all to whatever objects are stored as values in the dictionary.

If multiple threads have a reference to an instance of `Item` and are updating its properties, all sorts of unpredictable things can happen.

To directly answer the question:

> What is the correct way to go about handling a situation where two processes are accessing one shared list where there is the possibility one process has changed properties of an entity of that list which the other process requires?

There is no correct way to handle that possibility. If you want the code to work in a predictable way you must eliminate that possibility.

It looks like you might have hoped that somehow the two operations will stay in sync. They won't. Even if they did, just once, it might never happen again. It's unpredictable.

*If* you actually need to set the `Uri` and `Response` to null, it's probably better to do that to each `Item` in the same thread right after you're done using those values. If you do those three things

- Execute the request for a single `Item`
- Do something with the values
- Set them to null

...one after another in the same thread, it's impossible for them to happen out of order.

(But do you need to set them to null at all? It's not clear what that's for. If you just didn't do it, then there wouldn't be a problem to solve.)